# Firestore reference in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having some issues referencing a particular collection that is nested (I think that the term) I have attached an image of my database structure below:

[image]

EDIT: image of Foods collection
[image]

I basically have multiple documents that have a collection within them with the same name. Is there a way I can dynamically select the "Foods" collection depending on the restaurant ID that a user has clicked on the previous page. ie if the user selects a restaurant with ID 01, it should Load "Foods" from a document with ID 01, etc.

here is my code for the fragment loading the foods:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.hostapp.Adapters.FoodAdapter;
import com.example.hostapp.Models.FoodModel;
import com.example.hostapp.R;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;


public class MainsFragment extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference menuref = db.collection("Foods");


    private FoodAdapter adapter;

    String restaurantid = "";


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mains, container, false);


        Query query = menuref.whereEqualTo("menuid", restaurantid).orderBy("name");

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<FoodModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<FoodModel>().
                setQuery(query, FoodModel.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FoodAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_mains);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        return view;
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

for the previous page on click:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.example.hostapp.Adapters.RestaurantAdapter;
import com.example.hostapp.Adapters.categoryCardAdapter;
import com.example.hostapp.Models.Restaurant;
import com.example.hostapp.Models.categoryCard;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

public class RestaurantList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference restaurantref = db.collection("restaurants");
    private RestaurantAdapter adapter;

    String categoryid="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurant_list);

        setUpRecyclerView();
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView(){


        //Get intent
        if(getIntent() != null)
            categoryid = getIntent().getStringExtra("categoryid");
        if(!categoryid.isEmpty() && categoryid != null)
        {
            Query query = restaurantref.whereEqualTo("categoryid", categoryid).orderBy("name");

            final FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Restaurant> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Restaurant>().setQuery(query, Restaurant.class).build();

            adapter = new RestaurantAdapter(options);

            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.restaurant_recycler);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            adapter.setOnItemClickListerner(new RestaurantAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
                    Restaurant restaurant = documentSnapshot.toObject(Restaurant.class);
                    Intent foodlist = new Intent(RestaurantList.this, Foodlist.class);
                    foodlist.putExtra("restaurantid", documentSnapshot.getId());
                    startActivity(foodlist);

                }
            });
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `restaurant ID` exist in the documents within `Food` subcollection? Add also a picture of that?

Comment: yes it exists as "menuid", I've added a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments, to get all `Food` documents that exist in all sub-collections according to the `menuid` property, a [Firestore collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) is needed. This query looks like this:

```
Query menuIdQuery = db.collectionGroup("Foods").whereEqualTo("menuid", yourMenuId);
```

Comment: thank you so much, once I add my restaurantid, I get an error line:

 ```private CollectionReference menuref = db.collectionGroup("Foods").whereEqualTo("menuid", restaurantid);```

is it my COllection reference that I change or the query itself?

Comment: error: incompatible types: Query cannot be converted to CollectionReference

Comment: Change the `CollectionReference` to `Query`, does it work now?

Comment: yes, it does, thank you, now I'm just building indexes, hope it works when they are done,

Comment: hi, last thing regarding the security rules,

is this the right format?

 match /{path=**}/Foods/{doc} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }

my firestore recycler is still empty

Comment: If you have a hard time when trying to implement the security rules, please post a new question, so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: thanks, i figured it out, the reason it's not loading is because putExtra isn't passing the restaurantID from the activity to the menu Fragment.